# Como bajar archivo de Excel desde el servidor WEB?

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo Excel 2007 (extensión xlsx) en un directorio del servidor (externo a la raiz web), la  pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo bajarlo desde un link de una web?

> Para más claridad el archivo es e:\clientes\empresa\prueba.xlsx
>
> Tengo una web en http://localhost/web/
>
> Necesito bajar ese archivo prueba xlsx mediante un link en
>   http://localhost/web/index.html

He probado con este código `PHP`

```
$archivo = "e:\clientes\empresa\prueba.xlsx";

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $archivo);

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-   officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');

header('Content-Length: '.filesize($archivo));

readfile($archivo);
```

El archivo baja pero al momento de abrirlo con Excel 2007 no lo reconoce como archivo válido.

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Prueba así:

```
<?php
// Asegurate de que es un archivo realmente válido
// Recuperamos el archivo
$archivo = "e:\clientes\empresa\prueba.xlsx";

// Nos aseguramos que el archivo exista
if (!file_exists($archivo)) {
    echo "El fichero $archivo no existe";
    exit;
}

// Establecemos el nombre del archivo
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'. 'Excel_'.date('dmYHis').'.xlsx"');

// Esto  
// header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-   officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
// lo cambiamos por esto
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

// Indicamos el tamaño del archivo 
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($archivo));

// Evitamos que sea cachedo 
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

// Realizamos la salida del fichero
readfile($archivo);

// Fin del cuento
exit;
?>
```

Comment: no, el mensaje de Excel al intentar abrir el archivo cambia a "el Archivo que intenta abrir tiene otro formato que el especificado por la extensión del archivo" pero igual Excel no lo reconoce... en este caso al abrirlo muestra solo caracteres extraños.

Comment: Si, totalmente seguro, el archivo lo abro manualmente y abre correctamente, de la extensión ya cambié por xlsx e igual no funciona.

Comment: Pues es muy raro, lo acabo de probar en mi servidor (copiar-pegar el ejemplo, editar URI) y funciona perfectamente. He corregido la extensión en el ejemplo aun que me ha funcionado con las 2. no se que puede ser entonces. Asegurate de que no mandas ningun caracter algun espacio o algo antes del <?php

Comment: Opté por independizar la función y ejecutarla por fuera de la aplicación, funciona correctamente, así que me pondré a revisar algo de configuración de los script, archivo .htaccess y demás ... les agradezco su colaboración ...

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con este, este código tiene ya un tiempo que lo utilice y para funcionar correctamente requiere la librería PHPExcel.

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
$nombre = "NombreArchivo";  
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$nombre.xlsx\"");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, "Excel2007");
    $writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
    $writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);
    $writer->save("php://output");
    exit;
```

Comment: en realidad lo que el usuario necesitaba era saber como definir la cabecera y ya lo tienes!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizando una diferente variable para el nombre y otra para hacer referencia a la ubicación del arhivo.

```
$archivo = "e:\clientes\empresa\prueba.xlsx";
$nombre = "prueba.xlsx";

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $nombre );

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-   officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');

header('Content-Length: '.filesize($archivo));

readfile($archivo);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta ... no funciona, el archivo baja pero Excel no lo reconoce ...